# descendant selector not working for .v-data-table th {*some style*}

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a v-data-table with table headers and the styling is inside the .vue component. When I use the following style

```
.v-data-table-header th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Nothing happens to the table headers. I have also tried other css like background and text colors and nothing is happening. I checked the dev tools and there are definitely th elements and it doesn't seem like the style is being overridden by anything since it's not even showing up in the styles tab of the dev tools. If i just use .v-data-table-header the style is applied. What could be going on here?

edit:
here is the vue code

```
<v-expansion-panel>
  <v-expansion-panel-header>
    Example header
  </v-expansion-panel-header>
  <v-expansion-panel-content>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="someHeaders"
      :items="someItems"
    />
  </v-expansion-panel-content>
</v-expansion-panel>
```

Here is the html for the table:

```
<div class="v-expansion-panel-content__wrap">
    <div data-v-7037ec41="" class="v-data-table v-data-table--has-bottom theme--light">
        <div class="v-data-table__wrapper">
            <table>
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="">
                    <col class="">
                    <col class="">
                </colgroup>
                <thead class="v-data-table-header">
                    <tr>
                        <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-label="Name: Not sorted. Activate to sort ascending."
                            aria-sort="none" class="text-start sortable"><span>Name</span><i aria-hidden="true"
                                class="v-icon notranslate v-data-table-header__icon material-icons theme--light"
                                style="font-size: 18px;">arrow_upward</i></th>
                        <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-label="Path: Not sorted. Activate to sort ascending."
                            aria-sort="none" class="text-start sortable"><span>Path</span><i aria-hidden="true"
                                class="v-icon notranslate v-data-table-header__icon material-icons theme--light"
                                style="font-size: 18px;">arrow_upward</i></th>
                        <th role="columnheader" scope="col"
                            aria-label="Message: Not sorted. Activate to sort ascending." aria-sort="none"
                            class="text-start sortable"><span>Message</span><i aria-hidden="true"
                                class="v-icon notranslate v-data-table-header__icon material-icons theme--light"
                                style="font-size: 18px;">arrow_upward</i></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="text-start">r3_ibmmq_jms_0.1</td>
                        <td class="text-start">Routes/MICROSERVICE</td>
                        <td class="text-start">cMQConnectionFactory component
                            "cMQConnectionFactory_1":MQTT_RECONNECT_DELAY of cMQConnectionFactory was changed to 10</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="text-start">r4_ibmq_jms_job_0.1</td>
                        <td class="text-start">Routes/MICROSERVICE</td>
                        <td class="text-start">cMQConnectionFactory component
                            "cMQConnectionFactory_1":MQTT_RECONNECT_DELAY of cMQConnectionFactory was changed to 10</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="v-data-footer">
            <div class="v-data-footer__select">Rows per page:<div
                    class="v-input v-input--hide-details v-input--is-label-active v-input--is-dirty theme--light v-text-field v-text-field--is-booted v-select">
                    <div class="v-input__control">
                        <div role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="list-101"
                            class="v-input__slot">
                            <div class="v-select__slot">
                                <div class="v-select__selections">
                                    <div class="v-select__selection v-select__selection--comma">10</div><input
                                        aria-label="Rows per page:" id="input-101" readonly="readonly" type="text"
                                        aria-readonly="false" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                                <div class="v-input__append-inner">
                                    <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--append"><i aria-hidden="true"
                                            class="v-icon notranslate material-icons theme--light">arrow_drop_down</i>
                                    </div>
                                </div><input type="hidden" value="10">
                            </div>
                            <div class="v-menu">
                                <!---->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="v-data-footer__pagination">1-2 of 2</div>
            <div class="v-data-footer__icons-before"><button type="button" disabled="disabled"
                    class="v-btn v-btn--disabled v-btn--icon v-btn--round v-btn--text theme--light v-size--default"
                    aria-label="Previous page"><span class="v-btn__content"><i aria-hidden="true"
                            class="v-icon notranslate material-icons theme--light">chevron_left</i></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="v-data-footer__icons-after"><button type="button" disabled="disabled"
                    class="v-btn v-btn--disabled v-btn--icon v-btn--round v-btn--text theme--light v-size--default"
                    aria-label="Next page"><span class="v-btn__content"><i aria-hidden="true"
                            class="v-icon notranslate material-icons theme--light">chevron_right</i></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is inside `v-data-table-header`? Could you show us the HTML?

Comment: @Anye added my vue code

Comment: @Anye also just added the html

Comment: Okay. Does any CSS property work on the `th`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The vue component was using 'scoped' styles which stops styling from applying to child components. I removed the scoped from `<style scoped>` and now it works as expected.